# Difference between String[] arg and String[] args?

Tags: java

Is there a difference between `String[] args` and `String[] arg`?

My assignment is to misspell certain things in a `HelloWorld` program.

When I misspelled `args` as `arg` in:

```
public class HelloWorld {
     public static void main(String[] args) {
          System.out.println("Hello, World");
```

The program compiled and ran correctly.  So I'm trying to understand why `arg` worked just as well as `args`.

Is `arg` just an alternate spelling for `args`, or is there a difference between the two?

EDIT:  I just tried misspelling `args` as `ars`, and the program compiled and ran correctly again.  I'm definitely confused now.

Comment: Because it's a variable name, you can call it `maroun` as well (very recommended).

Comment: Yes, it's only spelling.  'args' is (by convention) the variable name for command-line arguments variable for java.

Comment: "I'm definitely confused now" - You shouldn't be, you edited the question after you saw the answers... As already mentioned, the variable's name is up to you, the type is important and Java expect the `main`'s parameter to be of type `String[]`.

Comment: You can name variables whatever you want, and method parameters are no different (with a few exceptions of course). The answers provided I think clearly show this. The String[] parameter being called `args` is nothing more than a standard.

Comment: Thank you everyone for your VERY QUICK responses :)

Comment: Don't forget to **accept** the correct answer that helped you @Axebeard2025

Answer (score 6):

There is no difference. Java distinguishes types, variables names are just for you

Answer (score 6):

As long as you are not using the variable, whether you specified it as `args` or `arg` makes no difference. The bytecode doesn't store the type actual name. It knows that there is a variable assigned that accepts a `String[]`.

Answer (score 1):

You can call it what ever you want. It is the name of your argument.
What really matters is the signature of the method.

When a java class is executed from the console, the main method is what is called. In order for this to happen, the definition of this main method must be

```
public static void main(String [])
```

Naming parameter as args is a standard convention, but not strictly required.

In Java, args contains the supplied command-line arguments as an array of String objects.

In other words, if you run your program as

```
java HelloWorld one two
```

then args will contain

```
["one", "two"]
```

Answer (score 1):

the `arg` and `args` are the variable names for the type you have declared.

These variables name can be anything, though there are some restrictions over it.

You can refer to [here](http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=58) for help in setting variable names.

Answer (score 0):

No. There is no difference. The arg syntax is there mainly for compatibility with C syntax

Answer (score 0):

There is no difference. Variable names are important to you and, in general, the compiler only cares if the variable exists.

Now, about the main method, the following signatures are valid and equivalent:

```
public static void main(String[] args);
public static void main(String args[]);
public static void main(String... args);
```

However, `javap` output is different, the var-args is preserved:

```
String[]
Compiled from "HelloWorld.java"
public class HelloWorld {
  public HelloWorld();
  public static void main(java.lang.String[]);
}
```

Notice the difference:

```
String...
Compiled from "HelloWorld.java"
public class HelloWorld {
  public HelloWorld();
  public static void main(java.lang.String...);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

While other answers made it clear, and since I cannot write this in a comment, I'll make it an answer.

Maybe a little explanation about the [`main`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/getStarted/application/#MAIN) method signature will help you to understand what is *important* for Java:

> ... You can name the argument **anything you want**, but most programmers choose "args" or "argv".
>
> ... This array is the mechanism through which the runtime system passes information to your application.

- `main` is declared `void` because once it finishes, it doesn't mean that the program finished. If it spawns a *new thread* it might be that these threads are still running.
- It is `public` because it is called by the JVM to run the method which is outside the scope of project.
- ... and is `static` because when the JVM calls it, there is *no object* existing for the class being called. So it has to have `static` method to allow this from class.

Comment: You should add the relevant JLS part about main method, this way your answer will be complete :)